# IPTables in Ubuntu SURVIVE restart

Tags: ubuntu, iptables

I'm trying to find out why the rule `-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE` keeps surviving reboots. I don't have `iptables-persistent` installed, there is no `/etc/iptables.rules` file or additional lines in `/etc/network/interfaces`

The server is a DigitalOcean droplet with Ubuntu 12.04.3 x64

Comment: `iptables -F && iptables-save`?

Comment: Nope, still there after rebooting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, the line was in `/etc/rc.local`. I wonder who put it there...

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running iptables-save on the server after you've made the changes? This should write the current iptables rules to a file that will be loaded on subsequent boots.

Comment: Yes, I've already tried that. The rule keeps appearing after rebooting